# Running a single unit test class is working, Running all classes only executes the first test class

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

I am facing a strange behaviour with Android Unit Tests.
In my test package I have a collection of UnitTest classes. If I right-click one of these classes and let them run, all is good. But when I right-click the package and want to run all tests within this package, only one of the classes is executed. The other tests are ignored (see screenshot)

When I run `gradlew test`, I get the following output for almost all test classes:

```
com.my.project.GalleriesTest > classMethod FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Any idea how I can run all my tests at once? Or any idea where to continue digging?

[image: UnitTests]

Comment: Post more code. And you don't have just one test case in each Tests.java file or something do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Philip
Sorry for not posting the answer yet. I ran the tests using by clicking on the gradle task in the "Gradle Tab" of Android Studio. For some reason this gave me more detailed output which led me to the solution. All my tests were extending a BaseTest class. In this class I started the MockWebServer without stopping it. That's why first test runs without problems, but all following tests could not run,  because the MockWebServer was already started and could not be started a second time.